# Is there a better way to connect an array of QPushButton's to a slot so each button has a unique identifier when pushed?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I am creating a checkers board as part of a university assignment. There has been very little teaching around the GUI side of things. So I may have overcomplicated this project a bit and become stuck while trying to access the clicks from the board GUI.

I have read about lambda's in the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html for signal mappers, but, I am not sure if it is right for the application I am coding. I have tried to implement the signal mapping so that when a particular button is pushed on the checker's board, the slot can identify it with its unique signal.

If there is a better way, or if lambdas are the best way, could you please explain how to implement this?

At the moment, my current code can't access the clicks made. I also get an error for the `connect()` function:

> no known conversion from 'void QAbstractButton::* (bool)' to 'const char*' for the second argument.

```cpp
connect(&checkers[i], &QPushButton::clicked, signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
```

However, this compiles but does not work:

```cpp
connect(&checkers[i], SIGNAL(clicked), signalMapper, SLOT(map));
```

Below is more complete code for greater context.

Constructor and board set function:

```cpp
// Constructor
GameWindow::GameWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::GameWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    BoardSetup(4);
}

/* Sets up the initial gameboard display with the other game information displays also being
* initialised. The game board is an array of QpushButtons that have there Icon
* changed according to where the pieces are on the board.
* Called by the GameWindow Constructor*/
void GameWindow::BoardSetup(int size)
{
    {
        QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this->checkers);
        connect(signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::mappedInt, this, &GameWindow::SquareClicked );
        bool col=1;
        for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            col=!col;
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                if(col == 1)         // logically check to see what Color the square needs to be.
                {
                    checkers[i+j*size].setGeometry(QRect(width/size*j,width/size*i,width/size,width/size));
                    checkers[i+j*size].setFixedSize(QSize(width/size,width/size));
                    checkers[i+j*size].setStyleSheet("background-color: black");
                }
                else if(col==0)
                {
                    checkers[i+j*size].setGeometry(QRect(width/size*j,width/size*i,width/size,width/size));
                    checkers[i+j*size].setFixedSize(QSize(width/size,width/size));
                    checkers[i+j*size].setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
                }
                col=!col;
                signalMapper->setMapping(&checkers[i], i);
                connect(&checkers[i], &QPushButton::clicked, signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
            }
        }
        Grid = new QGridLayout;
        Grid->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,width,width));
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                Grid->addWidget(&checkers[i+j*size], j, i, Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignCenter);
            }
        }
        GridGroup = new QGroupBox();
        GridGroup->setLayout(Grid);
        ui->BoardGrid->addWidget(GridGroup);
        ui->BoardGrid->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,width,width));
        ui->BoardGrid->addWidget(GridGroup);
        setWindowTitle("Checkers Game");
        ui->P1PieceCount->setFontPointSize(40);
        ui->P1PieceCount->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ui->P2PieceCount->setFontPointSize(40);
        ui->P2PieceCount->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ui->TurnCount->setFontPointSize(40);
        ui->TurnCount->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ui->Player2Name->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        
        CheckersBoard(size);
        SetInitialDisplay(size);
    }
    return;
}
```

How I am trying to access the clicks.

`GetClicks()` and `WaitForClick()` functions:

```cpp
/* This function will get the clicks that are required to make the human move.
 * Called by GameWindow::HumanMove */
void GameWindow::GetClicks()
{
    connect(this, &GameWindow::SquareClicked, this, &GameWindow::WaitForClick);
}

/* This function will get the clicks that are required to make the human move.
 * Called by GameWindow::GetClicks via signal SquareClicked */
void GameWindow::WaitForClick(int square)
{
    firstclick = !firstclick;
    unsigned int test=square;
    if (firstclick ==0 && test != StartPos)
    {
        StartPos = square;
        checkers[square].setChecked(1);
    }
    else if (firstclick == 1 && test == StartPos)
    {
        checkers[square].setChecked(0);
    }
    else if (firstclick==1 && test!= StartPos)
    {
        EndPos = square;
    }
}
```

The `StartPos` and `EndPos` clicked are used in a possible move function to validate the move. It is then updated to the GUI.

Any help on how best to implement this signal and slot mechanism would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but it is highly recommended to post [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, 'However, this compiles but does not work' - is there any output to the console/debugger log?

Comment: If you just want to know who call the slot, use QObject::sender() function.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what a debugger log is? The output works as it is GUI based and it shows and acts as expected to a point. There was no error code in the console.

Comment: Will the QObject Sender Return QPushbutton or would it return checker[int]? It is the int that I require. Thanks.

Comment: sender() gives you name of QPushButton object in this case. Then you can easily find object you're looking for in checkers[].

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Qt calculator example`?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html

you can connect multiple buttons to the same slot.

in slot,  find out which button sent the signal using QObject::sender().

Once have the button, extract the position using MyButton::Pos().
(MyButton is the widget used for each of the board button)